# How do i add items to a observablecollection from another list view

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Hi I am a beginner with Xamarin forms and need some help. I have tried looking for this method everywhere.

I have a List view with a lot of animal names. When a item is clicked it shows more info about that particular animal. I have added a button that is on each animals info page. I would like to click that "add" button, that would then add the name off the animal to another List view.

But I am stuck on how to do this, any help would be greatly appreciated.

this is the first list page in code behind

```
public partial class BirdListAZ : ContentPage
    {
        IEnumerable<birdlistmodel> GetBirds(string searchText = null)
        {
            var birds = new List<birdlistmodel>
            {
                new birdlistmodel (){Id = 1, BirdNames = "Apalis, Bar-throated" }, 
                new birdlistmodel (){Id = 2, BirdNames = "Apalis, Yellow-breasted"},//there are alot more birds here
        
            };
            if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(searchText))
                return birds;
            var lowerBirds = searchText.ToLower();
            return birds.Where(c => c.BirdNames.ToLower().StartsWith(lowerBirds));
        }

        public BirdListAZ()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            blistview.ItemsSource = GetBirds();
        }

        private void SearchBar_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            blistview.ItemsSource = GetBirds(e.NewTextValue);
        }

        private void blistview_ItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var birds = e.SelectedItem as birdlistmodel;
            Navigation.PushAsync(new BirdPages(birds.BirdNames, birds.BirdSelect));
        }
    }
}
```

this is the content page for that code behind

```
 <ScrollView HeightRequest="3000">
            <StackLayout>
                <SearchBar 
                    TextChanged="SearchBar_TextChanged"
                    Placeholder="Search Bird"
                    PlaceholderColor="Gray"
                    HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                    FontSize="Small"
                    FontAttributes="Italic"
                    VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Start"/>
                <ListView x:Name="blistview" BackgroundColor ="AliceBlue" HasUnevenRows="True" ItemSelected="blistview_ItemSelected">
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ViewCell>
                                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Padding="5">
                                    <Label Text="{Binding BirdNames}" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Center"/>
                                    
                                </StackLayout>
                            </ViewCell>
                        </DataTemplate>

                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>
            </StackLayout>
        </ScrollView>
```

when item is clicked on list it displays that info in a separate page
the contentpage

```
   <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <Label x:Name="BirdNameCall" FontSize="30" FontAttributes="Bold"
                VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" 
                HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
            <Button Text="+" x:Name="AddToList" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center" WidthRequest="200" HeightRequest="100" 
                    FontSize="30" BackgroundColor="Transparent" Clicked="AddToList_Clicked"/>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

So this is what i have done. I know the filewritealltext makes a new file each time. how can i just add to that file so a new file is not created?

```
 public BirdPages(string BirdNames, Button BirdSelect)
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            BirdNameCall.Text = BirdNames;
            AddToList = BirdSelect;
            localPath = Path.Combine(FileSystem.AppDataDirectory, birdfile);
        }

        const string birdfile = "birdlist.txt";

        string localPath;
        private void AddToList_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string BirdNames = BirdNameCall.Text;
            File.WriteAllText(localPath, BirdNames);
            DisplayAlert(BirdNames, "added to list", "Ok");
        }
```

So it works when i populate the list view but it will be a letter per row and not the entire string in a row

```
public partial class myBirdList : ContentPage
    { 
   
        public myBirdList()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            localPath = Path.Combine(FileSystem.AppDataDirectory, birdfile);

            birdlistview.ItemsSource = File.ReadAllText(localPath);



        }
        const string birdfile = "birdlist.txt";
        string localPath;
    }
```

Comment: you have to show us your actual code, not give us a vague description.  Are both of thse ListViews on the same page?  Or different pages?  Please read [mcve] and [ask]

Comment: Sorry i am new to this. They are on different pages. will attach code below

Comment: not yet. Still struggling with it :(

Comment: You could check below,the usage is roughly as follows.

Comment: Have you tried using MessagingCenter?

Comment: Refer to my update on `Birdpages` and `myBirdList`. This is what i have done now still need some help. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this is what I have done. I had to change a bit.
The added Bird Name needs to go to a blank list. So I created a new Observable Collection here. And this is where the Bird Name needs to be added.

```
    public partial class myBirdList : ContentPage
    {
       public ObservableCollection<string> Birdsadded { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<string>();



        public myBirdList()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            BindingContext = this;

            MessagingCenter.Subscribe<BirdPages, birdlistmodel>(this, "Add", (sender, arg) =>
           {
               Birdsadded.Add(arg.ToString());
           });

        }
    }
}
```

Then the sender is where I am having issues. And can't figure out how to send the bird name.

```
    public partial class BirdPages : ContentPage
    {
        public BirdPages(string BirdNames, Button BirdSelect)
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            BirdNameCall.Text = BirdNames;
            AddToList = BirdSelect;
        }

        private void AddToList_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            birdlistmodel bird = xxx// this is what i don't understand, what should be added here 
            MessagingCenter.Send<BirdListAZ, birdlistmodel>(this, "Add", bird );
        }
    }
}
```

thanks for your time and input I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [MessagingCenter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/messaging-center) to achieve this.

Using `MessagingCenter.Send` to pass the new data in your `AddToList_Clicked` method of `BirdPages`

then you will get the callback in another page which you want to add the new items with `MessagingCenter.Subscribe` method.In the callback method,you could add the new data to the new listview.

For example:

In the listview page which you want display a list and add the new data.

```
public partial class BirdListAZ : ContentPage
{
  public ObservableCollection<string> Birdsadded { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<string>();
  public BirdListAZ()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        blistview.ItemsSource = GetBirds();
        MessagingCenter.Subscribe<BirdListAZ, string>(this, "Add", async (sender, arg) =>
        {
            Birdsadded.Add(arg);// when you click add button in other page,it will handle this
        });
    }

}
```

in the page which you want to add the data:

```
public partial class BirdPages : ContentPage
{
    public BirdPages(string BirdNames, Button BirdSelect)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        BirdNameCall.Text = BirdNames;
        AddToList = BirdSelect;
    }

    private void AddToList_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string birdname = xxxx;
        MessagingCenter.Send<BirdListAZ, string>(this, "Add",birdname );
    }
}
```

Comment: I just can't seem to get this right. where you specified "birdlistmodel bird = xxx;// this is what you want to add to the list" I want the BirdNames to be added but I can't get it to work.

Comment: You could check the update,if you want to add birdname(type of string),you just need change `birdlistmodel bird = xxx` to `string BirdNames` and change `MessagingCenter.Send<BirdListAZ,string>` , `MessagingCenter.Subscribe<BirdListAZ, string>`

Answer (score 0):

OK so i got it to work to some extent. I am not creating and writing to a txt file and then reading from it in mybirdlist page. This is where i write to text file

```
       public BirdPages(string BirdNames, Button BirdSelect)
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            BirdNameCall.Text = BirdNames;
            AddToList = BirdSelect;
            localPath = Path.Combine(FileSystem.AppDataDirectory, birdfile);
        }

        const string birdfile = "birdlist.txt";

        string localPath;
        private void AddToList_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string BirdNames = BirdNameCall.Text;
            using (var writer = new StreamWriter(localPath, true))
                {
                writer.WriteLine(BirdNames);
            }
            DisplayAlert(BirdNames, "added to list", "Ok");
        }
```

Then i read from it into a list. Last question i have is how can i read each name into a lable. Now all the added birds displays in one label. And is it possible to not duplicate a name? Here is the code

```
 public myBirdList()
        {
            
            localPath = Path.Combine(FileSystem.AppDataDirectory, birdfile);
            
            string text = "";
            using (var reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(localPath))
            {
                text = reader.ReadToEnd();
            }
            InitializeComponent();

            birdlistview.ItemsSource = new List<birdlistmodel>
            {
                new birdlistmodel {Voellist = text }

            };
        }
        const string birdfile = "birdlist.txt";

        string localPath;
    }
```

Comment: You could mark it as a solution.It may help others.